# SEO URL not properly Multiwebsite magento2

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, seo

We have created  a multiwebsites. But the product url is not formatting correct seo-urls. I have tried to added the URL Rewrite in admin section, but its not working. The product url showing as  "**www.example.com/catalog/product/view/id/3/s/demo/**" But  need to display like www.example.com/categorykey/productkey.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Url Rewrite module for your URL key rewrite,

[Url Rewrite In Magento 2](https://github.com/Iazel/magento2-regenurl)

Check Above Github link for your URL rewrite.

You can url rewrite for category, product as well as only specific product and specific category using above module.